# @Karate Gatling is not generating report when i hit the endpoint once

Tags: scala, karate

My Gatling Simulation class,

```
class <MyClass> extends Simulation {
  before {
    println("Simulation is about to start!")
  }
  val smapleTest = scenario("test").exec(karateFeature("classpath:demo/get-user.feature"))
  setUp(
    smapleTest.inject(rampUsers(1) over (10 seconds))).maxDuration(1 minutes)
  //).assertions(global.responseTime.mean.lt(35))
  after {
    println("Simulation is finished!")
  }
}
```

My get-user.feature file,

```
Scenario Outline: Hit wskadmin url
    Given http://172.17.0.1:5984/whisk_local_subjects/guest 
    And header Authorization = AdminAuth
    And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
    When method get
    Then status <stat>
    * print result
    Examples:
      | stat |
      | 200  |
```

When i run the simulation class, below console logs i am getting:

```
Simulation com.karate.openwhisk.performance.SmokePerformanceTest started...
13:20:48.877 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO  i.gatling.core.controller.Controller - InjectionStopped expectedCount=1
13:20:49.473 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: null 
13:20:49.525 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] I am here in get-user
13:20:49.706 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - request:
1 > GET http://172.17.0.1:5984/whisk_local_subjects/guest
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Authorization: Basic d2hpc2tfYWRtaW46c29tZV9wYXNzdzByZA==
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Type: application/json
1 > Host: 172.17.0.1:5984
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_144)

13:20:49.741 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 34
1 < 200
```

**Note:** Here i am getting the response in 34 mili seconds, but gating is unable to generate the report. Below is the error message i am getting

**Error:**

> ```
> Generating reports...
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
>   at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: There were no requests sent during the simulation, reports won't be generated
>   at io.gatling.charts.report.ReportsGenerator.generateFor(ReportsGenerator.scala:48)
>   at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.generateReports(RunResultProcessor.scala:76)
>   at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.processRunResult(RunResultProcessor.scala:55)
>   at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:68)
>   at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:45)
>   at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:37)
>   at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
>   ... 6 more
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Total time: 14.199 s
> [INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-24T13:20:50+05:30
> [INFO] Final Memory: 30M/332M
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.gatling:gatling-maven-plugin:2.2.4:test (default-cli) on project
> ```
>
> openwhisk: Gatling failed.: Process exited with an error: 255 (Exit
>   value: 255) -> [Help 1]

But if i run the same simulation file simple change in feature file as below

```
Scenario Outline: Hit wskadmin url
        Given http://172.17.0.1:5984/whisk_local_subjects/guest 
        And header Authorization = AdminAuth
        And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
        When method get
        Then status <stat>
        * print result
        Examples:
          | stat |
          | 200  |
          | 200  |
```

Then gatling generates the report.
Please help me someone what is the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your interest in karate-gatling and the very detailed report.

This [is a bug](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/460), which we have fixed and just made a release for.

Can you upgrade your karate-gatling version to 0.8.0.1 and let me know how it goes ?

Comment: Thank you Peter, it is working now after upgrading the version. But i have one question, how do we pass parameters to a feature file when we call the feature file in simulation class through karateFeature method? I did not find any method to pass paramenters(to feature file) in the library. It would be really helpful if you can help me on this.

Comment: @ManojMishra looks like you are new to StackOverflow. first do you mind marking this answer as "accepted" ? then open a new question, thanks.